# How to conduct fft with fftw on eigen matrix?

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, eigen, fftw

I want to conduct 2d fft on eigen matrix, and when i write my the function of 2d-fft which can accept the input eigen matrix, i have to copy the eigen data into the pre-allocated memory with fftw_malloc, so the efficience is low.

```
fftw_complex* input1 = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * row * col);
fftw_complex* output1 = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * row * col);
fftw_plan forwardPlan = fftw_plan_dft_2d(row, col, input1, output1, FFTW_FORWARD,  FFTW_ESTIMATE);

MatrixXcd FFT_R(const MatrixXd& inputdata){
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            input1[i * col + j][0] = inputdata(i, j);
            input1[i * col + j][1] = 0.0; // Imaginary part is set to 0 for real input
        }
    }
    
    fftw_execute(forwardPlan);

    output1_(row, col);
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            output1_(i, j) = std::complex<double>(output1[i * col + j][0], output1[i * col + j][1]);
        }
    }
```

I expect one way to optimize my code, is there one solution to avoid the data copy?

Comment: Did you check the [Eigen-FFT module](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__FFT__Module.html)? It provides a wrapper for fftw (the linked docu is probably not helpful, but you can check [the source](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/unsupported/Eigen/src/FFT/ei_fftw_impl.h) how it uses fftw, or [the unit tests](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/unsupported/test/fft_test_shared.h) how it can be used.

Comment: @chtz thank you for your answer, i know the eigen-fft, but the information somewhere i have looked is that eigen-fft is slower than the origin fftw, i don't know why.

Comment: Eigen provides a wrapper for fftw. You need to compile with `-DEIGEN_FFTW_DEFAULT`: https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/unsupported/Eigen/FFT#L85

Comment: You don't have to copy. Eigen's [default alignment](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPreprocessorDirectives.html) is at least as strong as FFTW's, under normal circumstances. See also the discussion here: [How can I use FFTW with the Eigen library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71608557/how-can-i-use-fftw-with-the-eigen-library/71610461#71610461)